# Telerik Grid: Add dropdown in edit mode - C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Please be gentle... I'm very rusty :)  But I'm working on a project where I've started with a Telerik Grid built in the code behind.  I need to add an edit column that when selected, gives me a dropdown of choices for one field.

I've spent the last three or four days plowing through the Telerik forum and tutorials and can't for the life of me find anything that seems to address this.

I'm very grateful for a nudge in the right direction!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Multiple ways to achieve that. Please post your code.

Comment: Really haven't gotten anywhere at all with it @Win ... I have the basic data columns built out in C#, now I need to add the edit column and the dropdown.  I've tried using many examples, none of which have worked.

From what I gather on Telerik's site, this all needs to be done programatically in the code behind so many of their examples don't seem to apply.

Comment: Telerik Grid Edit has few options - InLine, [Edit Form and Popup](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/edit-form-types/defaultcs.aspx); each has own way of doing things. In addition, are you using DataSet, DataTable or Generic List?  Without knowing where you at, my answer won't be effective.

Comment: First off... thank you @Win.  I appreciate your time, sincerely.  What I'm trying to do is very much like this: 

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/comboingrid/defaultcs.aspx?product=combobox , what they are using for the "category" column.  I'm getting my data from a LINQ query, also in my codebehind file.

Sorry, I'm a tad fried after days of beating my head against this... but thanks!

Comment: hard to give answer without seeing how the grid is built in C#.
Have you tried adding a GridDropDownColumn to the grid ? You probably will have to configure a datasource for the choices.